# System.InvalidOperationException Stack empty when using StructureMap MVC5 package

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, structuremap, structuremap3, displayfor

After installing StructureMap.MVC5 package got next exception System.InvalidOperationException Stack empty. in case when you try to display circular object dependency with partial view.

```
@model WebApplication.Models.Test

@foreach (var val in Model.Tests) {
     @Html.Partial(val.GetType().Name, val) 
}
```

or just

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Tests)
```

Object example:

```
public class Test
{
     public ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

Any thoughts how it is possible to resolve?

Thanks!